# rails use capistrano to deploy and restart?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, passenger

I try to use capistrano to deploy my app, all problem in setting capistrano were fixed, except...

**I can't auto restart server after deploy**, here is my code:

gemfile:

```
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.3'#, group: :development
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1'
gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.0'
gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1.2'
gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.1.1'
gem 'capistrano3-delayed-job', '~> 1.0'
gem 'capistrano3-nginx', '~> 2.0'
```

capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/passenger'
require 'capistrano/delayed-job'
require 'capistrano/nginx'

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

deploy.rb:

```
require "whenever/capistrano"
`ssh-add` # need this to make key-forwarding work

set :whenever_identifier, ->{ "#{fetch(:application)}_#{fetch(:stage)}" }

set :application, 'devops'
set :repo_url, 'mygit'

set :rbenv_type, :user 
set :rbenv_ruby, "2.2.2"
set :rbenv_path, "/home/john/.rbenv"
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
set :rbenv_map_bins, %w(rake gem bundle ruby rails)
set :rbenv_roles, :all 

set :deploy_to, '/home/john/devops'
set :log_level, :debug

set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push("bin", "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "vendor/bundle", "public/system")
```

deploy.rb

```
namespace :deploy do

# I try following code:
#---
after :deploy, cap nginx:restart 
run "sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart"
run "touch tmp/restart.txt"
after :deploy, cap production passenger:restart
after :deploy, cap production deploy:restart
#---

# invoke 'delayed_job:restart'

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      within release_path do
        execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

P.S. when I type "touch tmp/restart.txt" on local(after **cap production deploy**), my page doesn't change with my modification, I always need to use "sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart", how can I fix this problem?

I try this, but also no response(no error msg):

```
after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'

namespace :deploy do

    desc "Restart application"

    after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'

  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 1 do
      execute :touch, release_path.join("tmp/restart.txt")
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

For passenger to restart app you should `touch/restart.txt` on server, not local:

```
namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Restarts Phusion Passenger
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
    end
  end

end
```

There's no point in restarting nginx itself, unless you're upgrading passenger for example.

Also restart is not instant, requests are routed to new code only after it has started

Comment: I tried "touch/restart.txt" on server side, and it's no response, I also tried your solution, but not work...

Comment: on server, I try "touch current/tmp/restart.txt" or "touch /home/john/devops/current/tmp/restart.txt", all work, but when I try your solution or "execute :touch, current_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')", no response...